# Is it possible to anchor pages while doing another action in HTML / JS?

Tags: javascript, html

There's a product page that sells something. On this product page, on the top, it says "Reviews." Once you click it, it'll go down to the bottom of the page where there are four tabs -- Specs, Customer Reviews and other tabs.

**What I want:** to scroll down to the anchor point and then open up the tab that says customer service. Is this possible?

**Here's the code I have so far:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>My Homepage</title>
    <link href="tabs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />



</head>
<body>

<!-- Here's the button to link --->
<a href="#linkMe">Link here</a> 
<!-- Here's the button to link --->

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<h1>My Homepage</h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<!-- Here's the anchor to link down to --->
<a name="linkMe"></a>
<!-- Here's the anchor to link down to --->

<!-- Here are the tabs, select tab #2 to open --->
<ol id="toc">
  <li><a href="#page-1"><span>Page 1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#page-2"><span>Page 2</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#page-3"><span>Page 3</span></a></li>
</ol>
<!-- Here are the tabs, select tab #2 to open --->

<div class="content" id="page-1">
    <h2>Page 1</h2>
    <p>Text...</p>
</div>
<div class="content" id="page-2">
    <h2>Page 2</h2>
    <p>Text...</p>
</div>
<div class="content" id="page-3">
    <h2>Page 3</h2>
    <p>Text...</p>
</div>
<script src="activatables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
activatables('page', ['page-1', 'page-2', 'page-3']);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, this is the Customer Reviews URL anchor when clicked. I need to implement but I don't exactly know how: http://fumethis-com.3dcartstores.com/POWER-SERIES-ZERO-STARTER-KIT_p_8.html#page=page-3

**My Main Concern**

Will it work on mobile devices, too? So on a Mac using Safari, it will not work but from Windows 8, it seems like it worked once but I forgot how I set it up.

Comment: Mike, don't delete the question - it makes the answers meaningless and makes the whole q&a useless for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using `jQuery` (and I'm sure someone will suggest a method that doesn't) this is quite simple.

```
function scrollTo(selector){
    window.scroll(0, $(selector).offset().top);
}

$('a.whatever').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    scrollTo($(this).attr('href'));
}
```

This will fallback to a basic anchor link without JS, so you can still use IDs as normal. You might want to add `- 10` after `.top` to ensure there's a little space above the element you're scrolling to, but that depends on your margins/padding.

#### Where to add it

The best way to handle JavaScript is to link to a remote script. Add this to the base of your HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/page.js"></script>
```

Then create the directory `js` and the file `page.js` (or whatever works, e.g. if you're on the home page, call it `home.js`) which contains the code above. Make sure this comes after your inclusion of jQuery.

Comment: Thanks again. As I've asked someone previously, can you please tell me where in the original code would I insert the code you've just written by example? Thanks.

Comment: I added the HTML you'd need to include it in your page. Unsure why you unaccepted my answer but if that code works please consider re-accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: Yes, it's possible.

**Extended answer**:
First add an `onclick` event to the anchor tag:

```
<a onclick="scrollToAnchor('the-id')">Link</a>
```

and the function looks like this:

```
//javascript
function scrollToAnchor(target){
    //scroll to the target
    document.location.hash = target;
    //open the tab
    theMethodThatOpensTheTab();
}
```

if you have included jquery, this tasks turns quite simple:

```
<a href="#target" class="scroll-to">Link</a>
```

and then

```
$('a.scroll-to').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //scroll to the target
    document.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
    //open the tab
    theMethodThatOpensTheTab();
});
```

Comment: So my question to you now, after this helpful comment is where do I add these codes in? Where in the original code I posted above does it go?

Comment: I update my answer. Add the javascript code (it is commented) inside the `javascript` element. As you can see, the `theMethodThatOpensTheTab()` is the function that opens the tab in your code or the library you use.